# How to manually pop view controller from the stack pushed via Show Detail segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a segue of type: `Show Detail` linked to the `UITableViewCell` from **Master View Controller**. Within **Detail View Controller** in `viewDidLoad` I try to override `leftBarButtonItem`:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-menu"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("menuButtonTapped:"))
```

The method I call is following:

```
func menuButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

But it doesnt want to work. Method is called, but there is no pop action, because `navigationController` has there only one controller in `viewControllers` array. When I do not try to override `leftBarButtonItem`, everything is fine, there is a default **Back button** and when I tap it, the controller pops from the stack. What goes wrong?

Comment: What are trying to accomplish? Do you need to override the `leftBarButtonItem`'s implementation or do you want to customise the button?

Comment: Need to customise the button, but then I need to customise the action also... and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the use of **Master View Controller** and **Detail View Controller** in the question, I'm assuming you're using a `UISplitViewController`. If this is the case, your **Detail View Controller** is not going to be found in your `UINavigationController`. You should definitely check [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISplitViewController) on the `UISplitViewController`.

Secondly, the `UIBarButtonItem` that appears when you select a cell on your table view is generated automatically by the `UISplitViewController`. The logic behind this button is explained in the previous link I posted. If all you need is customise its appearance, I'd suggest you check [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html) on the matter as well. Replacing that `UIBarButtonItem` seems like overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

Moreover, I'm not quite sure why you'd need to override the button's action. Since this is a `UISplitViewController`, this button is not going to be visible on all possible interfaces. So your custom action is not always going to be executed. Couldn't you perform your custom code on the Detail View Controller's `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` methods?

Finally, if the solutions above still don't fit your needs, here's what you could do:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.splitViewController?.delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeToDisplayMode displayMode: UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode) {
        if displayMode == .PrimaryHidden {
            self.previousButton = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icon-menu"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("menuButtonTapped:"))
        }
    }

    private var previousButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    @objc func menuButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //your custom code

        if let target = self.previousButton?.target as? NSObject {
            target.performSelector(self.previousButton!.action)
        }
    }  

}
```

I haven't tested this, but I think you'll get the idea.

Also: *please note that this is a bit hacky and I'd only recommend doing this as a last resource.*